# Meteor Bootstrap Whatsapp tutorial

Tags: angular, meteor, whatsapp

I am following the Whatsapp tutorial located at this page: https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp/meteor/bootstrapping

When I executed this command:

```
meteor npm install angular@^1.5.8 --save
```

Then this message was displayed:

```
no matches found: angular@^1.5.8
```

Is this tutorial not up-to-date? Which version should I put to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, i can't tell if the tutorial is up-to-date or not, but i will give you full details on how to get this done the easy way.

First, it is very important you follow process of installation step-by-step together with any dependencies to avoid error.
an updated procedure can be found here: https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup

In the above tutorial, they focus on the Ionic CLI; they use it to serve the client and build the project using Cordova, and they use Meteor as a platform for their server, so they were be able to use Mongo collections and subscriptions.

1. Ensure you have Node.js version 5 or higher installed. if you haven't, do so here: https://nodejs.org/en/
2. Install Ionic and cordova globally: `$ npm install -g ionic cordova`
3. create your Whatsapp-clone using the following command:
   `$ ionic start whatsapp blank --cordova --skip-link`
4. Then add a declarations file with a wildcard module to allow third party libraries to be used in your app even if they don't provide their own type declarations:`create a file src/declarations.d.ts` that contains this line; `declare module '*';`

you can start your app by typing this `$ ionic serve` into your terminal.

You can then go through the rest of the tutorial for your complete app. click the link above to the tutorial. hope it helps? thanks.